# How to properly get the width of a string in Swift iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8

I've read a number of SO posts about this, but couldn't find anything that worked.

My code :

```
let englishTextSize    = englishString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)])
let englishLabel       = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, 150, englishTextSize.width, englishTextSize.height))
```

This code snippet causes an ellipses around my text thus obviating that the width isn't great enough.

The text itself uses a lot of obscure characters like :

```
svarūpe-'vasthānam
```

But I can't imagine that throwing it off that much. Open to any tips in Swift or Obj-C though preferably Swift!

Comment: Why not use sizeToFit to make it perfectly adjusted and then set its center?

Comment: @Eiko Sounds promising! First time I've heard of this. I'm just one week into swift dev.. Care to share an example?

Comment: I've given an example in Swift below - maybe you need to adjust a thing or two. Maybe the label is an outlet from a xib or storyboard file; but you should see the point. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code could be as simple as this:

```
let englishLabel = UILabel(CGRectZero)
label.text = englishString
label.sizeToFit()
label.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 150)
```

Comment: This snippet does in deed look amazing. But when add this, no text appears at all.

Comment: Ah I see how this works. I think my text was just displaying somewhere else after I made your update. This is truly the answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: Just a small follow up.. but when I do CGRectZero.. FitToSize() doesn't seem to respect the width of its container frame. And so the text ( which is multi lined ), just bleeds off the right side. But if I set a CGRectMake, then I can explicitly say `self.view.frame.size.width - 40`  . Is there something I'm missing that's also a simple way to define frame boundaries for a UILabel? Or should I just set the width as an additional attribute?

Comment: First, it's unusual that the size measurements don't match... are you sure you're using the same font? There are measurement methods for some given bounds, but this comes down to your approach. Maybe you should resort to let autolayout do the job, but this is rather out of scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Depend of the attribute

```
let englishTextSize = englishString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14)])
let englishLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, 150, englishTextSize.width, englishTextSize.height))

print(englishLabel.text.sizeWithAttributes(orderAttributes).width)
```

Comment: This is essentially the exact same thing I wrote above except you're printing the results of my non-working width.

Comment: Make sure your englishString is not empty otherwise I don't see why it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Below code works perfectly for me.Hope it will help you as well...

```
    let name = "Statue of liberty"
    let size = (name as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)])
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to calculate the width yourself. You can use `sizeToFit` to make the width and height to fit the text, then change the frame to the height and origin you wanted.

Something like:

```
[englishLabel sizeToFit];
[parentView addSubview:englishLabel];
englishLabel.center = [parentView convertPoint:parentView.center
                                  fromView:parentView.superview];
```